# How to call a procedure as part of SQL statement using psycopg2

Tags: postgresql, psycopg2

How would I go about executing the following insert using psycopg2?

```
INSERT INTO file (name, volume) 
VALUES ('foo', (select id from volume where volume.name='bar'));
```

This of course does not work :

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO file (name,volume) VALUES (%s,%s)","foo","(select id from volume where volume.name='bar')")
```

`select id from volume where volume.name='bar'` could be replaced by a call to stored procedure :

```
lookup_vol_id('bar')
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You would use the `INSERT...SELECT` form of `INSERT`, e.g.:

```
INSERT INTO file (name,volume)
SELECT 'foo', (select id from volume where volume.name='bar');
```

Or if `name` and `column` are the only columns in that table, in that order, you can leave out the column names entirely:

```
INSERT INTO file
SELECT 'foo', (select id from volume where volume.name='bar');
```

Either *SQL* string can be passed into `cursor.execute` (without the semicolon).

As an aside, it looks like perhaps the `volume` column should be renamed `volume_id`, since it's the `id` column from the `volume` table.

Answer (score 0):

I can't test it now, but I would expect something like this to work:

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO file (name, volume) "
               " VALUES (%s, "
               "   (SELECT id FROM volume WHERE volume.name = %s))",
               "foo", "bar")
```